# Magento 1.9.3.2 backend product image not uploaded

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, catalog

I hope you all are doing great .

I am working on a magento website backed to upload product. Then I saw that image upload not working. There is no js error. Also after browse image button when I upload it uploaded successfully. But the image is not showing on the list. Below is the screenshot you may understand good.[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on your media Folder.
You can use the [cleanup tool](https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php) to set all permissions automatically
Just copy the magento-cleanup.php in your magento root and run it from your browser

Comment: I already did that

Answer (score 0):

Delete Browser cookies & cache. I have fix same issue after update to magento 1.9.3.6.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/112147)

Comment: this is solution i have fix problem with this way